# How to force execution of code at form show

Tags: delphi, message

I have the following code in a unit that I include as the last unit in my uses list

```
{ TFormHelper }
procedure TForm.WMMoving(var aMessage: TWMMoving);
var
  rec: ^TRect;
  wrk: TRect;
begin
  wrk := GetWorkArea;
  rec := Pointer(aMessage.DragRect);
  if rec^.Left < wrk.Left then
    begin
      rec^.Right := rec^.Right - (rec^.Left - wrk.Left);
      rec^.Left := wrk.Left;
    end
  else if rec^.Right > wrk.Right then
    begin
      rec^.Left := rec^.Left - (rec^.Right - wrk.Right);
      rec^.Right := wrk.Right;
    end;
  if rec^.Top < wrk.Top then
    begin
      rec^.Bottom := rec^.Bottom - (rec^.Top - wrk.Top);
      rec^.Top := wrk.Top;
    end
  else if rec^.Bottom > wrk.Bottom then
    begin
      rec^.Top := rec^.Top - (rec^.Bottom - wrk.Bottom);
      rec^.Bottom := wrk.Bottom;
    end;
end;
```

It is supposed to check if a form is inside the working window of my main form and if not then it should move the form to a valid position.

In the form I want to check I put

```
SendMessage(Handle, WM_MOVING, 0, 0);
```

in the FormShow event, but it has no effect.
I know the function works because if I try to drag the form with the mouse it is moved to a valid position at once.

So my question is: how can I force the code to run when form is shown?

Comment: Has no effect, or triggers an access violation? You're passing null pointers for the two message parameters, so what do you expect your message handler to use for `rec`?

Comment: The FormShow action has no effect. It doesn't trigger any AV

I can see what you are saying about the REC - any suggestions as how to change this

Comment: I don't see how that code could run. It's a helper? And you expect a helper to handle messages. That's not going to happen. You need to derive a class from `TForm` and handle messages in that class.

Comment: @TLama - that does the trick and my form are moving as they should.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - I can't see why this should not be working. I have been using this helper for preventing forms moving out of screen for a very long time.
The problem I have now is because I have 'normal' form that I want to be sure never is shown outside the main forms available area (below top ribbon and above bottom statusbar)

Comment: Is it really a helper in the technical term? `class helper for`?

Comment: I see our point there David - the code is in fact something I inherited from a colleague quite some years ago and I am not sure that he was using helpers as one can do today so the { TFormHelper } should maybe be removed as it is not a true helper. In fact it declared like TForm = class(Forms.TForm) - I will chang my code :-)

Comment: OK. That clears it up. You just need to extract the code in `WMMoving` into a separate function that receives a rect as its parameter. Call that function from `WMMoving` and also call it from an overriden `DoShow`. And you are done. But you cannot send `WM_MOVING`, it's not in your gift. It's wrong to do so..

Comment: I think this should be titled *How to force execution of code in a WM_MOVING handler*. The code in FormShow runs, it just doesn't have an effect.

Answer (score 3):

To run code when a form is shown, put code in the `OnShow` event handler.

---

That's not your problem, though. Your problem is that your code has no *effect*. The `wm_Moving` message is normally sent *while a window is being moved by the user*, as during a drag operation. The OS continually sends the message to ask the form where it's allowed to go, including tentative window coordinates where the window will be moved to. The window responds to the message by adjusting the proposed window bounds, and then the OS either moves the window to those new coordinates or changes the drag rectangle (depending on whether the "full window drag" option is set).

Merely sending a lone `wm_Moving` message doesn't do any of that, though. You're essentially asking the form where it wants to go, but since you're playing the role of the OS in this scenario, you still need to *act* on the results you get and actually move the window. The `wm_Moving` message is a notification, not a command; it has no inherent side effects of its own.